# Using ".0e0" to check for integers in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have used the following to check for integers in my program:

```
 If IsNumeric(verticalval + ".0e0") Then
                verticalinteger = True
```

However, I am just wondering why this works as surely .0e0 is an alphanumeric value and so if I were to input 55, it would become 55.0e0 which is alphanumeric but still passes as an integer.

Comment: It's [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation). `5e0` = `5*10^0` = `5`.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ Could you please explain how the following is working? Am not understanding the codes! Thanks

Comment: `"546"` is a string that represents a number in decimal notation whereas `"546.0e0"` represents the same number, it's just written in scientific notation. It's a notation that makes it easier to represent very large or very small numbers. Numbers in scientific notation are always represented as `m * 10^n`. `e` is shorthand for the `10^` part. So, any integer number with `".0e0"` appended (`10^0` = `1`) is not altering its value; however, other number formats (hexadecimal, for example), with the `e0` appended, should cause a failure. Appending the notation is further restricting the input.

Comment: @Cory Thank you. What I don't understand is how this differentiates between an integer and a non integer/decimal. In the end, it's to the power of 0 which is inevitably 1...

Comment: Because if verticalval were say 55.1, it's then implicitly converted to a string so that ".0e0" can be concatenated, which gives the string "55.1.0e0" . This cannot be parsed as an integer by IsNumeric.